# What is the use of Google Settings app?

Tags: google-settings

I'm using low config Android mobile, Google Settings app occupy my phone memory so I wonder to know what are the uses of behind this app and once I delete how come get back this app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This app is actually part of the [Google Play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) app. Google automatically updates Google Play services on all supported devices via Google Play Store to ensure API consistency across devices and versions, and to deliver fixes and [new features](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) in a timely fashion.

It is installed on any Android device running Android 2.2 or higher and is updated every 6 weeks and the updates are pushed silently to all supported devices meaning if you uninstall it then it will be re-installed automatically.

It also allows Google to patch some vulnerabilities in Android without requiring a full O/S update or involving manufacturers/carriers.

Answer (score 3):

This will contain all settings related to your Google Account like search settings, Ads settings, location and others. And more importantly, you will not be able to uninstall this app.

Comment: You **could**, in theory, uninstall it on a rooted device, but much in the same way you **could** throw the phone down a flight of concrete stairs! Best to stay well away from it!